# Reactive (java) way to read and accumulate records from a stream

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming, smallrye

New to Reactive Programming here.

Inside a [Multi](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/getting-started/creating-multis) transform, I need to accumulate bytes for few iterations, examining incoming bytes and when I encounter a particular byte pattern, I publish the
entire accumulated byteArray for further consumption.

Seems like a simple requirement but I'm stuck.

*Pseudo Kotlin code:*

```
   val array = listOf<ByteArray>(....)
   Multi.createFrom().items(array)
       .onItem.transform { oneByteArray: ByteArray ->
            if (oneByteArray.indexOf(0x0d) == -1) {
                // somehow accumulate oneByteArray somewhere (1)
                // do not publish anything downstream (2)
            } else {
                // publish accumulated byteArrays as one large byteArray
            }
    }
```

I'm stuck on (1) and (2). What are the mechanics of temporarily stopping the publication downstream (while I'm looking for a specific byte) ?

Comment: This has nothing to to do with webflux, or spring project reactor so removing the tags.